# How to prove polynomials with degree $n$ does not form a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, field-theory, vectors

This is one of my linear algebra problems:

> Prove that polynomials of degree $n$ **does not** (The professor made these words bold intentionally) form a vector space.

From what I read, the set of polynomials of degree $n$ should be a vector space, because:

1. There is an "One" and a "Zero" in this set;
2. We can find inverse for addition and multiplication from this set;
3. It follows all the axioms of addition.
4. It follows all the axioms of scalar multiplication.

Then can someone give me some hints to prove it does not form a vector space?

Comment: What would be the zero? Also, vector spaces do not have a "one".

Comment: Not closed under difference of polynomials.

Comment: Well, your first axiom says $0$ is in the vector space.  Of what degree is the zero polynomial?

Comment: p=0 haven't degree n for all n

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I am thinking if we set $a_0, a_1, \dots, a_n$ to be 0, then we can get the zero?

Comment: What is the definition of "degree" you are using?

Comment: @B.Goddard Would that be degree $-1$?

Comment: Your professor is talking about polynomials exactly of degree $n$, but you are thinking of polynomials of degree *at most* $n$ (which indeed form a vector space).

Comment: @HansLundmark Yeah that might be the problem. Could you please tell me more about the difference between polynomials exactly of degree $n$ and polynomials of degree at most $n$?

Comment: To sum up these comments:  $0$ is not a degree $n$ polynomial.  Some people define the degree to be $-1$, but I find that artificial, even though it makes some theorems a little cleaner.

Comment: @B.Goddard $-1$ is a rather poor choice of degree for the zero polynomial because then the degree function isn't additive. The degree I usually see is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Polynomials of degree $n$ **does not** form a vector space because they don't form a set closed under addition.

For instance:

$$X^n-X^n=0$$

which is not of degree $n$.

So, don't get confused with the set of polynomials of degree **less or equal** then $n$, which form a vector space of dimension $n+1$. We often work with this space.

Comment: That's based on convention. It's actually very useful to say zero has every degree. For example, let $[k[x]]_d$ denote the set of all homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ in one variable $x$ with coefficients in $k$. Then we usually consider $[k[x]]_d$ a $k$-vector space. Hence, we are assuming zero has every degree. But the idea of your example is absolutely correct, just take $(x^n+1)-x^n=1$ instead. Now we can all agree $1$ is a degree zero polynomial, regardless of conventions.

Answer (score 8):

Polynomials of degree $n$ is a set which is not closed under addition. For example, if $n=3$, then $x^3+x^2$ and $-x^3$ are both $3$rd degree polynomials but their sum is not:
$$
x^3+x^2-x^3=x^2
$$
(which is not a $3$rd degree polynomial).